# Disable TypeScript notifications from Gulp in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2015, aurelia

I just did an npm update on my Aurelia CLI project, and now I'm suddenly getting Toast notifications from Gulp for TypeScript compilation errors in Visual Studio 2015, which is really, really annoying.

Can anyone provide guidance on how to switch this off? Also, does anyone know of any recent changes to Node packages that would cause this behaviour to start happening?

Answer (score 0):

The compilation is disabled by opening the .csproj file for the project and add the following line, right after the `TypeScriptToolsVersion` element:

```
<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
```

UPDATE:
In RC2, you can disable it by adding TypeScriptCompileBlocked to the .xproj file.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>True</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: It's an ASP.NET Core project, is there an equivalent for that project type?

Comment: I think the problem is in the Aurelia CLI build system, not Visual Studio - the notifications are coming from a Gulp task called transpile.

Answer (score 0):

To remove this you would want to modify your transpile.js file to remove gulp notify - you would do this here:

https://github.com/aurelia/cli/blob/3c5ea5f935e523d1cec5ead884391d6b008deee5/lib/resources/tasks/transpile.js#L22

If someone is coming later to look for the same thing from a skeleton it is here in build/tasks/build.js -

https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/blob/master/skeleton-typescript/build/tasks/build.js#L26

I remove this on my TypeScript problems because it emits too many issues when refactoring code.

Comment: That's the one. Do you know what's happened to the version of TypeScript? It looks like the Node package is now 2.1.1, but the Visual Studio package release is only up to 2.0.6, they are definitely not in synch anymore, I think that's why I started seeing the Gulp errors all of a sudden.